# When exporting from Publisher the PDF is set to "fit width". Can I change that to "fit height"?

Tags: pdf

My title says it all.  When I open an exported pdf from Publisher it is large filling my screen.  I would like to set the pdf to open smaller, "fit height" or about 75-100 percent. Any idea where those settings might be found?

Comment: That's a function of your PDF reader, not Publisher. Neither Adobe nor Foxit have a setting to "fit height", but "fit page" is likely your answer - I don't have Adobe Reader on this computer, but in FoxIt, it is in the VIEW section of the HOME tab, an icon that looks like a page with four arrows pointing up, down, left, right surrounding it.

Comment: As @JeffZeitlin states, set this in the PDF viewer... Sumatra PDF and PDF-XChange Viewer also have "fit page" and zoom settings, as well as page rotation, that *persist for each PDF file*. The first time you view a file, set its view appropriately, and the next time it's displayed by that viewer, it should keep its previous appearance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving your pub file as .pdf, in the file explorer popup, there is a button named "options" click on it and you could tell it how you want the pdf to be

For example, see this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some PDF-creation products have the ability to set the metadata of the
generated PDF document to display in a particular way when it's opened
in a PDF viewer.

However, Publisher does not have this capability. The options that it
supports are only:

[image]

What you can do:

- Set your PDF viewer initial view to "fit height" for all documents
  (if it supports this)
  as viewing preferences on your computer
- Use a third-party tool to set this option into the metadata
  of the PDF. One (commercial) product that can do that is
  [VeryPDF Advanced PDF Tools](http://www.verypdf.com/app/advanced-pdf-tools/index.html)
  using the
  [Set viewer preferences command](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfinfoeditor/pdf-tools-command-line.htm#Set_viewer_preferences_):
  `pdftools -i "C:\input.pdf" -o "C:\output.pdf" -q "FitV"`